# Reset the entire "Open with" menu including the programs in the part named "Other options"

Tags: windows, file, reset, explorer

I want to remove everything from the Windows 11 "Open With" menu, including everything in it, for example: the part called "Other options"

Here is a more representative image:

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0oLR.png)

I tried to reset explorer settings but it doesn't work...